# Using @Profile annotation with property place holder value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When we define profile for any component in spring, we declare it as
`@Profile(value="Prod")`. But i want to give that value from properties file.
Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean give that value to a properties file? Do you mean that you want to include a properties file only if a profile is active?

Comment: No..I want the profile name to come from properties file

Comment: Does `@Profile("${propertyName}")` work for you where `propertyName` comes from `application.properties`?

Comment: yes ..that would be great

Comment: Did you try and see if it works?

Comment: Ya...I tried like that but it doesn't work

Comment: Nor will it ever work. The `@Profile` annotation is there to indicate that a bean of configuration is only valid for a certain profile. It would beat the purpose of making that configuration imho. Why would you need a dynamic profile name anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going through the source code of Spring, I have arrived to the conclusion that what you are asking is not possible. To make this clear, it is not possible to have Spring evaluate `${property}` inside `@Profile`.

Specifically take a look at `ProfileCondition` which checks whether or not the profile is active.

```
class ProfileCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        if (context.getEnvironment() != null) {
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> attrs = metadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(Profile.class.getName());
            if (attrs != null) {
                for (Object value : attrs.get("value")) {
                    if (context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles(((String[]) value))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The meat is `context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles(((String[]) value))`.

Now if you check the source of `AbstractEnvironment` where `acceptsProfiles` resides, you will find that the control reaches

```
protected boolean isProfileActive(String profile) {
    validateProfile(profile);
    return doGetActiveProfiles().contains(profile) ||
            (doGetActiveProfiles().isEmpty() && doGetDefaultProfiles().contains(profile));
}
```

which does not attempt to evaluate the expression, but takes the String verbatim (also note that nowhere before `isProfileActive` is the String expression being evaluated either)

You can find the code I have mentioned above [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ProfileCondition.java) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.java).

---

One another note, I am not sure why you would need to have a dynamic profile name.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be trying to abuse the `@Profile` annotation. Use profiles for enabling functionality. Not for saying that a Bean is active in a specific environment.

A way to achieve something closer to what I think you are looking for, would be to have properties files specific to your environment, which define the profiles which should be active in them. This way, you can start your app with an arg such as:

```
--spring.profiles.active=prd
```

Spring Boot will then attempt to load `application-prd.properties`, where you could activate environment-specific profiles:

```
spring.profiles.active=sqlserver,activedirectory,exchangeemail
```

That way your beans will only be activated when the functionality they provide is required.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be when creating the ApplicationContext:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigClass.class);
String profile = aplicationContext.getEnvironemnt().getRequiredProperty("profile");
applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(profile);
```

Comment: this is for setting active profile but what i want his when  i create a component and set value for it that value should come from properties file

Comment: Also you probably don't want to be following such an approach when using Spring Boot

Comment: is it possible if i use any other properties file other than 'application.properties' and using @PropertySource annotaton

Comment: @DineshShende Did you get it to work? If so, then posting an answer to your own question would help future readers