# Can the @Profile annotation in spring use placeholders?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can the @Profile annotation in spring use placeholders?

I want @Profile annotation, but the value inside is ${spring.profile.active} which is obtained using a placeholder. Is this useful?

```
@Configuration
@Profile("${spring.profile.active:local}")
public class Config {

}
```

I want to know if ${spring.profile.active} can get the value correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Spring @Profile does not support SPEL for getting value from property. The same question asked in [Using @Profile annotation with property place holder value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602249/using-profile-annotation-with-property-place-holder-value/25603494#25603494)